# Free functions cannot have function visibility

Tags: testing, erc-1155, inheritance

I am developing my Dapp and as I am trying to compile and test my contract I keep getting an error saying that free functions cannot have visibility and I am very frustrated and confused as to what is going on. Here is some of my code.

```
    contract SpideyERC1155 is IERC1155, IERC1155Receiver, Ownable{

       using Address for address;

        // Mapping from token ID to account balances
       mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => uint256)) private _balances;

       // Mapping from account to operator approvals
       mapping(address => mapping(address => bool)) private _operatorApprovals;

       // Used as the URI for all token types by relying on ID substitution, e.g. 
       https://token-cdn-domain/{id}.json
        string private _uri;


       function balanceOf(address account, uint256 id) public view virtual override 
          returns 
         (uint256) {
          require(account != address(0), "ERC1155: address zero is not a valid owner");
            return _balances[id][account];
         }



       function balanceOfBatch(
         address[] memory accounts,
         uint256[] memory ids
      ) public view virtual override returns (uint256[] memory) {
          require(accounts.length == ids.length, "ERC1155: accounts and ids length 
           mismatch");

          uint256[] memory batchBalances = new uint256[](accounts.length);

          for (uint256 i = 0; i < accounts.length; ++i) {
             batchBalances[i] = balanceOf(accounts[i], ids[i]);
          }

            return batchBalances;
         }




        function isApprovedForAll(address account, address operator) public view virtual 
          override returns (bool) {
          return _operatorApprovals[account][operator];
         }




      function _setApprovalForAll(address owner, address operator, bool approved) public 
         virtual {
          require(owner != operator, "ERC1155: setting approval status for self");
          _operatorApprovals[owner][operator] = approved;
          emit ApprovalForAll(owner, operator, approved);
        }


        function _safeTransferFrom(
         address from,
         address to,
         uint256 id,
         uint256 amount,
         bytes memory data
       ) public virtual {
         require(to != address(0), "ERC1155: transfer to the zero address");

         address operator = _msgSender();
         uint256[] memory ids = _asSingletonArray(id);
         uint256[] memory amounts = _asSingletonArray(amount);

        _beforeTokenTransfer(operator, from, to, ids, amounts, data);

        uint256 fromBalance = _balances[id][from];
        require(fromBalance >= amount, "ERC1155: insufficient balance for transfer");
         unchecked {
          _balances[id][from] = fromBalance - amount;
        }
          _balances[id][to] += amount;

          emit TransferSingle(operator, from, to, id, amount);

          _afterTokenTransfer(operator, from, to, ids, amounts, data);

          _doSafeTransferAcceptanceCheck(operator, from, to, id, amount, data);
       }



        function _doSafeTransferAcceptanceCheck(
         address operator,
         address from,
         address to,
         uint256 id,
         uint256 amount,
         bytes memory data
       ) public virtual override{
        if (to.isContract()) {
         try IERC1155Receiver(to).onERC1155Received(operator, from, id, amount, data) 
      returns (bytes4 response) {
            if (response != IERC1155Receiver.onERC1155Received.selector) {
                revert("ERC1155: ERC1155Receiver rejected tokens");
               }
           } catch Error(string memory reason) {
               revert(reason);
           } catch {
            revert("ERC1155: transfer to non-ERC1155Receiver implementer");
            }
         }
       }


      function _safeBatchTransferFrom(
       address from,
       address to,
       uint256[] memory ids,
       uint256[] memory amounts,
       bytes memory data
     )public virtual override{
      require(ids.length == amounts.length, "ERC1155: ids and amounts length mismatch");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC1155: transfer to the zero address");

        address operator = _msgSender();

        _beforeTokenTransfer(operator, from, to, ids, amounts, data);

        for(uint256 i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
          uint256 id = ids[i];
          uint256 amount = amounts[i];

          uint256 fromBalance = _balances[id][from];
          require(fromBalance >= amount, "ERC1155: insufficient balance for transfer");
          unchecked {
            _balances[id][from] = fromBalance - amount;
          }
          _balances[id][to] += amount;
       }

       emit TransferBatch(operator, from, to, ids, amounts);

       _afterTokenTransfer(operator, from, to, ids, amounts, data);

         _doSafeBatchTransferAcceptanceCheck(operator, from, to, ids, amounts, data);
       }


  
      function _doSafeBatchTransferAcceptanceCheck(
       address operator,
       address from,
       address to,
       uint256[] memory ids,
       uint256[] memory amounts,
       bytes memory data
     )     public virtual override{
          if (to.isContract()) {
           try IERC1155Receiver(to).onERC1155BatchReceived(operator, from, ids, amounts, 
    data) returns (
            bytes4 response
          ) {
              if (response != IERC1155Receiver.onERC1155BatchReceived.selector) {
                revert("ERC1155: ERC1155Receiver rejected tokens");
              }
          }   catch Error(string memory reason) {
              revert(reason);
          }   catch {
              revert("ERC1155: transfer to non-ERC1155Receiver implementer");
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: If this is the code, then you are missing a curly bracket at the end.

Comment: @EGstacking The code you posted doesn't generate that error. That message usually means you have an extra `}`, or you are missing one. "Free functions" are functions outside a contract.